# Import module selectively in python

Tags: python

I'm working on a script where in debug/development mode I'd like to import `typing` package, but I don't want to have it in production one.

The reason I want to do it is because with this package I can use static code analyzers like mypy, while at the same time `typing` package as I found in few places online is expensive when it comes to loading. And since this script is supposed to be executed multiple times in the cloud I don't want to spend time (and money) on loading package that is useless in this case.

My initial idea was to do pseudo `#define` doing something like this:

```
if os.getenv('DEBUG', None):
    from typing import Any, Optional

def myfunc(self, param: str) -> Any:
```

But it wouldn't work in production environment, because I don't have `Any` there.

Is there any good solution for this?

Comment: Add at beginning of the module `from __future__ import annotations`. If your code doesn't request annotation data anywhere, they won't be evaluated then (and therefore no errors appear).

Comment: "but I don't want to have it in production one." I can't understand - what exactly are you trying to avoid? In your own words, exactly what do you think happens when you use such type annotations, and why would there be downsides to that in production? How exactly do you intend to "not have" `Any` in the production environment - are you planning to delete the `typing.py` file from your installation or something?

Comment: "at the same time typing package as I found in few places online is expensive when it comes to loading." Module import in Python is cached, wouldn't happen inside a loop anyway, and on my machine reloading `typing` takes about 1.3 milliseconds.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/strip-hints/